# Count number of points by name within distinct polygons

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join, count, st-intersects

In PostgreSQL/PostGIS I have 2 tables:

- A POLYGON table (`polytable1`) with shapes named 'Poly 1', 'Poly 2' etc... Each name can appear multiple times (i.e. 20 polygons with the name 'Poly 1')
- A POINT table (`pointtable`) where each point has a simple letter name ('w','x','y' etc) There are only 5 variations of name (only 4 shown in this example).

I want to create a copy of the `polytable` table (or just run as a SELECT output) but with new columns storing a count of how often a point falls inside it. The columns can be named after the point names.

To illustrate for an example, I'd like to take this scenario for `polytable1` and `pointtable`:

[image: postgis]

and produce this output for `polytable2`/SELECT view:

[image]

Comment: Do you know all possible point letters? How many are they?

Comment: @BERA yes there are actually just 5 letters in total. V,W,X,Y,Z

Comment: Since you get those errors; what _is_ the SRID of both geom columns? This is not an issue of any of the queries here.

Comment: Both are EPSG 27700

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
  polyname,
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='w') AS "w",
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='x') AS "x",
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='y') AS "y",
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='z') AS "z"
FROM 
    (select polygons.polyname,points.pid
    from polygons
    left join points
    on st_intersects(points.geom, polygons.geom)) sub  
GROUP BY polyname
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: A slight variation on this using `JOIN LATERAL` is:  `SELECT
  polyname,
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='w') AS "w",
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='x') AS "x",
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='y') AS "y",
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='z') AS "z"
FROM polygons
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT pid FROM points WHERE ST_Intersects(points.geom, polygons.geom)
) AS sub ON true
GROUP BY polyname`

Comment: @dr_jts Would that be faster or why use lateral join?

Comment: @BERA I get a `ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries
CONTEXT:  parallel worker
SQL state: XX000` using your solution.

Comment: @BERA, hard to say about which is faster.  Probably depends on the data.

Comment: As for your query, could the inner SELECT be removed, like this:  `SELECT
  polyname,
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='w') AS "w",
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='x') AS "x",
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='y') AS "y",
  count(pid) FILTER (WHERE pid='z') AS "z"
FROM polygons
    LEFT JOIN points
    ON st_intersects(points.geom, polygons.geom)
GROUP BY polyname`

Comment: making sure both tables where in the same SRID, this method works very well! I will try the others provided here too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code (I work in the schema **public**):

```sql
-- Creation of a new table : I use distinct to get one row for each value of polyname
CREATE TABLE polytable2 AS
SELECT DISTINCT polyname 
FROM polytable1 
ORDER BY polyname; 

-- Creation of four new fields : one for each letter with 0 as default value
ALTER TABLE polytable2 
ADD COLUMN w INT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN x INT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN y INT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN z INT DEFAULT 0;

-- Updating my 4 fields using a subquery that calculates the point count in each polyname value 
-- and then making a join between my two polygon tables. 
-- 4 updates, each time I change the name of the column and my letter in the where clause.
-- for the letter w
UPDATE polytable2
SET w = count FROM (SELECT polyname, count(*)
FROM polytable1, pointtable
WHERE letter = 'w' AND st_intersects(polytable1.geom, pointtable.geom)
GROUP BY polyname) as temp WHERE polytable2.polyname = temp.polyname ;

-- for the letter x
UPDATE polytable2
SET x = count FROM (SELECT polyname, count(*)
FROM polytable1, pointtable
WHERE letter = 'x' AND st_intersects(polytable1.geom, pointtable.geom)
GROUP BY polyname) as temp WHERE polytable2.polyname = temp.polyname;

-- for the letter y
UPDATE polytable2
SET y = count FROM (SELECT polyname, count(*)
FROM polytable1, pointtable
WHERE letter = 'y' AND st_intersects(polytable1.geom, pointtable.geom)
GROUP BY polyname) as temp WHERE polytable2.polyname = temp.polyname ;

-- for the letter z
UPDATE polytable2
SET z = count FROM (SELECT polyname, count(*)
FROM polytable1, pointtable
WHERE letter = 'z' AND st_intersects(polytable1.geom, pointtable.geom)
GROUP BY polyname) as temp WHERE polytable2.polyname = temp.polyname ;
```

I can explain more if you need.

Answer (score 4):

I think dynamic column names would be quite difficult. But if they don't need to be dynamic it sounds pretty simple:

```
select
po.poly_name,
sum(case when pt.point_name = 'w' then 1 else 0 end) as w,
sum(case when pt.point_name = 'x' then 1 else 0 end) as x,
sum(case when pt.point_name = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) as y,
sum(case when pt.point_name = 'z' then 1 else 0 end) as z
from
polytable1 po
left join pointtable pt on st_intersects(po.geom, pt.geom)
group by po.poly_name
```

Edit for OP:

```
select
po.poly_name,
sum(case when pt.point_name = 'w' then 1 else 0 end) as w,
sum(case when pt.point_name = 'x' then 1 else 0 end) as x,
sum(case when pt.point_name = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) as y,
sum(case when pt.point_name = 'z' then 1 else 0 end) as z
from
polytable1 po
left join pointtable pt on st_intersects(st_setsrid(po.geom, 27700), st_setsrid(pt.geom, 27700))
group by po.poly_name
```

Comment: column names will be static.

Comment: I also get a `ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries
CONTEXT:  parallel worker
SQL state: XX000` error with this.

Comment: One of your tables is not 27700, but if you say it is, then try the updated query.

Comment: ah it seems that one of my tables has been uploaded as SRS:900914. No idea where that came from! I'll retry

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you want to get, the following query will create a table with
polyname, pointname, count

```
SELECT polyname, pointname, count(*) as cnt 
FROM poly_table inner join point_table on (ST_Contains(poly_table.geom, point_table.geom)
GROUP BY polyname, pointname
ORDER BY polyname, pointname
```

A supposed the name of the geometry column in both table is "geom".
This way the zero count won't be stored.

The result should be:

```
Poly1   w   3
Poly1   x   6
Poly1   z   1
Poly2   w   6
Poly2   y   2
Poly3   w   2
...
```